# Geometric centroid and symmetry

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, geometric-group-theory

I have some intuition that for shapes with some rotational symmetry, the symmetry is typically about the geometric centroid.

For example, for a cuboid and cube this is true.

What about in general, for any object with rotational symmetry, how do we find / characterize the **point** about which it has rotational symmetry? It cannot be true that the object has rotational symmetry about arbitrary points.

Comment: I would say just average all points in the orbit of a vertex. For regular polygons, this can be phrased in terms of roots of unity. In the general case, I would average the points in the orbit of an extreme point.

Comment: Many times we ignore the details of the rotation. For example, if we have an equilateral triangle with vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$, we just specify the rotation as $A\to B\to C\to A$

Comment: There are cases where there's rotational symmetry about a single axis, so it's no good in such cases asking about a specific point.

Comment: Start by defining what exactly you mean by a "rotational symmetry" (opinions vary). For instance, a cube has a finite symmetry group that contains several different rotations (with different axes). It is quite possible that when you say a "rotation" you do not really mean it.